# URLSpan on Spanned Text not showing in drawn StaticLayout

Tags: android

I'm building a custom view that mimics TextView but which supports text wrapping by managing multiple internal StaticLayouts.

Everything is working out quite well, but I'm having trouble with viewing some HTML. Most of the HTML markup is translated to Spans via `Html.fromHtml`. This includes the a-link elements which, when I step through with the debugger, I can see are becoming URLSpan objects.

```
            mSpannedArticleText = Html.fromHtml(mInboundArticleText);
```

In the above, mInboundArticleText is the inbound string passed to setText and mSpannedArticleText is the Spanned object which will be passed to the StaticLayout. Everything in the StaticLayout renders great except *I cannot see the URLSpans.* I know they are attached to the mSpannedArticleText and I create a new StaticLayout using:

```
updatedLeftColumnLayout = new StaticLayout(mSpannedArticleText, mBodyTextPaint, leftColumnWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, (float) 1.0, (float) 0.0, true);
```

I'm not sure what would be causing this issue but, after looking at the source code for TextView, I can't seem to locate any special handling of URLSpans, nor do I see any exception cases in StaticLayout. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what I might be doing incorrectly in building the Spanned text or other requirements for using URLSpans which I might not have setup.

Comment: Doesn't TextView put all Spannable:s in DynamicLayouts when calling #makeNewLayout(..) though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured the issue out. The TextPaint apparently had the default linkColor set to be transparent so my links were there, but were just transparent.